# What could be causing this odd angular ui modal issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm a novice programmer trying to put together a web application with angular and node. I'm trying to incorporate the angular ui modal but having issues. The modal window, upon loading, seems to be rendering the html from the main page rather than the html from the template. However, as indicated below, the template is being loaded to the page.

What I'm looking for is not necessarily the answer to what is going wrong here (although that would be great) but rather advice on troubleshooting techniques for trying to determine the issue without resorting to stackoverflow for the answer in the future.

Screenshot of the issue:
[image: screenshot]

Node console:

[image: node console]

The following is my current code:

Parent and child controllers (addContent and newTerms respectively):

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('addContent', function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log){


$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.addTerm = function () {  
    var newTerm = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '../../views/partials/newTermModal.jade',
        controller: 'newTerms',
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    newTerm.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

}).

 controller("newTerms",function($scope, $modalInstance, items){

$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

});
```

I was thinking maybe it was an issue with the path to the template- should the path be relative to where the controller file is located? That is how I have it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller code looks OK to me, I also suspect it is an issue with the path to the template.

I personally have not had any success referencing the template's file location in `templateUrl` like you are doing.  What I usually do instead is add an `ng-include` to the bottom of my page:

```
<div ng-include src="'../../views/partials/newTermModal.jade'"></div>
```

I'm not familiar with jade, but assuming your angular template is structered like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="newTermModal.jade"> 
</script>
```

Then set `templateUrl` to just the `id` of the angular template:

```
templateUrl: 'newTermModal.jade'
```

To troubleshoot, I would check the console and inspect the **content** of `newTermModal.jade` and make sure it is what you are expecting.

Comment: Where are you including your template script? In the html page that will display the modal? Ideally (and as I have it now) I'd like to have a separate html/jade partial file for it. Jade is a templating language- I thought I'd give it a try just because it was used in the angular/express seed app. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah so at the bottom of your page that is displaying the modal, place the ng-include that references the file path to the separate html/jade template file.

Comment: Hmm, I've having issues getting the ng-include reference working. What should the path be relative to?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue however for a slightly different reason.
The `templateurl` was not set to a correct path in my case.
This implies that whenever either the `templateurl` is not found or is not a valid HTML (*jade is not valid HTML - it is compiled into valid HTML by pre-processors*) then angular just uses the parent html page(*i.e. the page from where the modal is being invoked from*).